# Fuzzing Python Modules

Tags: python, fuzzing

This question may seem a bit off but is it possible to fuzz a python module? I am currently learning all I can concerning the Peach fuzzing framework and I want to fuzz the python module: cx_Oracle in order to test its security. Can this be done? Because so far, all I've read about fuzzing tells me otherwise. Thank you!

Comment: Sure it's possible; you just apply your fuzzer to the public API of the module.  What gave you the impression it wasn't?

Comment: Lack of documentation to be honest. I am fairly new to all this, and have yet to fuzz the module. Thank you for your comment. Will try that soon!

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=fuzz+python+module

Answer (score 2):

One of the fuzzers that wasn't specified in @Neerav's answer is American Fuzzy Lop. You'll probably need to rebuild Python with AFL instrumentation, but in exchange you'll get an easy-to-use genetic fuzzer that learns how to modify input to generate new code paths. Also, you might find this talk interesting:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5kaqOKIqX_4

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonTestingToolsTaxonomy) is a list of Fuzz testing tools for Python. And, [Here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/743/what-are-some-tools-for-fuzz-testing) is a related question.

See if it helps.